# Spring Scheduling back up

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple spring application which has a Cron job like this.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class sampleClass {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * *")
    public void demoServiceMethod()
    {
        //executes something
    }
}
```

This works fine and executes every 30 minutes. Now i'm looking for a way that if the server is down at a certain time and if it misses this scheduling, a way to find out, so I can trigger another process to cover the server being down. I'm quite new to spring scheduling and the answer might be obvious, but I could not find it. So thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are, imho, 2 different things. Checking if the application is up and running and scheduling. Just create a job/thing that monitors your application, if it isn't running restarts it. That shouldn't be coupled to your scheduling mechanism. You could take a look at the `spring-boot-actuator` stuff (which can also run on regular applications) to get monitoring features out-of-the-box. Your exercise is then left to detecting the health of the server.

Comment: I would suggest you to record the timestamp for last successfully run scheduler. When the server is down and restarted, you can call a method which can check if it has been over 30 minutes since last successful run. If yes, then you can trigger your desired process to cover for server being down.